# Play Store Beta Testing "Group Not Found"

Tags: google-play

I'm trying to create a Beta versión of my App but i must be missing something.

I have created a google group and i have added a few emails, but when I try to add it to my Play account it saids "Group Not Found".

**I have tried with the email:**

mygroupname@googlegroups.com

**I have tried with my group URL**

https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mygroupname (if I click this link is working)

I have got the email and the URL from the group configuration console in the General Information area.

I have changed the security to the group to Public, and I still getting the same error message "Group Not Found".

**I have not tried with a Google+ community** because I do not even understand Google+ Circles and all that stuff (I'm just a Facebook guy).

Do I'm missing something in the group configuration??

Do I have to wait a few hours or something to access the Group via Play Store??

I'm really lost here.

Thanks and happy coding.

**UPDATE 1:**

In my google play console in the Beta Tab the version is in "Beta State" and in actions I can select "Move to production", "Move to Alpha" and "Deactivate".

I have tested my Google Group account and if I post a message all the members receive de message.

And I'm still getting the "Group Not Found" message in the Play console.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have found [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055196?hl=en#ts=3280770,6034692) and is not working, since the beginning all the owners of all the accounts have the same email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solved it.

The problem was that all the emails of the Google Group have to be members of the Play Store, so you have to ask to you users for the email that they use in their Android devices to access the Play Store.

At the end, I have learned how to create a Google+ Community and I'm using it, but I have tested the Google Group too and works like a charm.

I hope this will be helpful to someone.

Happy coding.